# Ember - Fetching live records with meta information

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have created a comment model and  trying to fetch all comments records. But I need a meta info **total comments** which is getting as a separate attribute outside comments array.

I am using Ember **store.query** to fetch records from rest service(**I tried store.findAll**, but it is giving me only record array of comments in promise response. Is it possible to modify that?). I am getting the **records with total comments(meta)** while using store.query(), but that record array is **not getting updated when we save new records**.

After doing some analysis I found that we can use filter for loading the live record, but filter is now deprecated in Ember(Ember 2.5.1). From the documentation It is clear that we can use ember-data-filter for loading live record. But I am confused to use that addon(Mentioned like it has some memory leakage issue) and **not sure whether I will get meta information from response**. Is there is any other way to fetch live records with meta information from the response.

Anyone please suggest a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some analysis, I found a solution to access meta data using store.findAll(). We can use **typeMapFor** in the findAll response to get the meta info in the response

```
store.typeMapFor(response.type)
```

Full code below,

```
store.findAll("comment").then(function(response) {
    var meta = store.typeMapFor(response.type);

    // your meta info will be in meta.metadata
    // var totalComments = meta.metadata.totalComments;
});
```

And the response record array is liveRecords which will get updated automatically, if we save new records.

```
store.query("comment").then(function(response) {
    var meta = response.get("meta");
    // We will get meta like this but reponse record array is not a liveRecords
});
```

Response getting from store.query() is just a recordArray (not liveRecords) which will not get updated with new records

Answer (score 0):

If you want an array of all records that updates as new records are populated you can use `peekAll` which returns a live record array.

**Added** Code sample:

```
loadRecords: function (){
    this.set('allComments', store.peekAll('comment'));
    this.store.findAll('comment');
},

recordCount: Ember.computed.alias('allComments.length')
```

Comment: But peek all will not make any network request. It will fetch data from data store only. What I have did currently is using store.query to fetch data from rest service and populate data store and after that using peekAll to fetch live record. But I am not sure whether this is the right approach.

Comment: @ManuBenjamin this doesn't access the meta (which was your question) but it is an example of a live record array that shows the current number of comments in the store as you load more from a server.

Comment: I will not be fetching all records in single query, but I will get the total records that present in the db as meta info in rest response. So what I need is the total comments in db not the count of comments in the store.

Comment: Personally I would likely just make it a separate request to get the information about the data. But your question was how to access the metadata, which it looks like you were able to access (pretty neat).

Comment: Yes @averydev..we can use store.typeMapFor to get meta data from find all response. Intially i didn't found this solution. Some recomended using store.query, after using that i got meta data(respose.get('meta')), but records return is not live records like we get from findAll. I guess you got my issue.